# Redirect subdomain to a specific directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, apache2, subdomain

I need to redirect a subdomain to a specific folder on hosting.

Example:

**store.mydomain.com** display content from: **mydomain.com/store**

**support.mydomain.com** display content from: **mydomain.com/support**

But I don't know how to do that, I don't know if I do it for DNS records, e.g. "CNAME", or if I do it via Apache, adding the "a2ensite" subdomain, or ".htaccess".

If it's via .htaccess, how do i access **mydomain.com/store** via **store.mydomain.com**?

I even tried to do it by adding the subdomain via apache. But without success.

Like the .conf file below:

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
    ServerName store.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin wbmaster@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/store

    <Directory /var/www/html/mydomain.com/store>
        Options -Indexes + FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

#LogLevel info ssl: warn

ErrorLog /var/www/html/mydomain.com.br/store/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/mydomain.com/store/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have full access to the vps host. My main domain has already set up and is working perfectly.

So I think this should be done via .htaccess, right? But how?

I know it's a very simple question, but I don't have much experience with .htaccess.

Thank you

Comment: After configuring the apache virtual host, you have to set the DNS for the subdomain which also indicates to your instance. A record or CNAME as you preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using Alias:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com/
    Alias /store /var/www/html/domain.com/store
```